# Black screen after dist-upgrade

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, updates

I just bought a laptop running 16.04.2 LTS Ubuntu. I executed the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

My Wifi went off in between for a second. After the `upgrade` completed, it asked for my password but then it completely went blank. There was just a cursor
on the screen. Even after force shutdown, after I login, all I see is a blank screen.

From tty1 screen when I type `startx`, I get a simple GUI screen with 2 folders.

What should I do ?

Answer (score -1):

Did you try this?

1. Boot into **recovery mode** and drop to a command prompt then run these commands:

> sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.old

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -phigh xserver-xorg
```

Comment: I have tried both of them but none works out.

Comment: *I have tried both of them but none works out.* As expected. You probably don't even have a xorg.conf file. Try completing the update with `sudo apt install -f` and reboot. It may fix itself. If not, there's a more serious problem.